# Is there any broadcast receiver to identify pin,password and lock pattern screen locks are on?

Tags: android

I created an application to unlock the phone but on changing the set  screen lock methods in location and security my application is bought behind screen locks . Is there any way to bring that in front?

when i completely kill my application and restarting , the application is working fine. But i need any other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [DeviceAdminReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html), this can listen for PIN, password but i'm not sure about lock patterm